# Why does my chart_flutter crash when I tap rapidly? (gives error '_drawAreaBoundsOutdated == false': is not true.)

Tags: flutter

I have looked at the similar questions on here but they don't seem to help.  Apologies if this is a duplicate somehow.

I'm using the charts_flutter package to draw a line chart and annotate it in response to user taps - so that data points at intersections can be read.  In the real app there are several of these linked but for simplicity I've removed that and still see the bug.

If the user taps steadily then all is well but if a few taps are received in quick succession then the chart crashes.

[image]

When the crash happens this is the message:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
'package:charts_common/src/chart/layout/layout_manager_impl.dart': Failed assertion: line 115 pos 12: '_drawAreaBoundsOutdated == false': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  LineChart file:///Users/chrisbennett/AndroidStudioProjects/charts_bug/lib/main.dart:115:29
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      LayoutManagerImpl.drawableLayoutAreaBounds (package:charts_common/src/chart/layout/layout_manager_impl.dart:115:12)
#3      BaseChart.drawableLayoutAreaBounds (package:charts_common/src/chart/common/base_chart.dart:438:22)
#4      _LinePointLayoutView.paint (package:charts_common/src/chart/common/behavior/line_point_highlighter.dart:418:30)
#5      BaseChart.paint.<anonymous closure> (package:charts_common/src/chart/common/base_chart.dart:603:12)
#6      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:313:8)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: ChartContainerRenderObject<num>#4b371
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=340.0, h=346.0)
...  semantic boundary
...  size: Size(340.0, 346.0)
RenderObject: ChartContainerRenderObject<num>#4b371
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=340.0, h=346.0)
  semantic boundary
  size: Size(340.0, 346.0)
====================================================================================================
```

The simplified version of the app is here to help you recreate the issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
       visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Tapping the chart causes a crash!'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: YVsX(),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class XVsYData {
  final double x;
  final double y;

  XVsYData(this.x, this.y);
}

class YVsX extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _YVsXState createState() => _YVsXState();
}

class _YVsXState extends State<YVsX> {

  static const  double _min = 1;
  static const  double _max = 90;
  static const int _numberOfDataPoints = 20;
  static final double _interval = (_max - _min) / _numberOfDataPoints;
  Map<String, XVsYData> _currentXAndYSelection = Map<String, XVsYData>();


  ///https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html
  static final List<charts.Series<XVsYData, double>> _dataPoints = [
     charts.Series(
      id: "Series 2",
      data: List.generate(_numberOfDataPoints, (index) {
        double x = (index*_interval)+_min;
        return XVsYData(x, x+2);
      }),
      domainFn: (XVsYData series, _) => series.x,
      measureFn: (XVsYData series, _) => series.y,
      colorFn: (XVsYData series, _) => charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
    ),
  ];


  ///TODO: Help jabbering (rapid tapping) at the chart causes a crash
   _onSelectionChanged(charts.SelectionModel model){
    final selectedDatum = model.selectedDatum;

    if(selectedDatum.isNotEmpty){
      selectedDatum.forEach((charts.SeriesDatum datum) {

        _currentXAndYSelection.containsKey(datum.series.displayName) ?
        _currentXAndYSelection.update(datum.series.displayName, (value) => XVsYData(datum.datum.x, datum.datum.y)) :
        _currentXAndYSelection.putIfAbsent(datum.series.displayName, () => XVsYData(datum.datum.x, datum.datum.y));

      });

      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(

      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
              Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-20,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
              child: charts.LineChart(
                _dataPoints,
                animate: false,
                selectionModels: [
                  charts.SelectionModelConfig(
                    type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
                    changedListener: _onSelectionChanged,
                  )
                ],
                behaviors: [
                  _currentXAndYSelection["Series 2"] != null ? charts.RangeAnnotation([
                    charts.LineAnnotationSegment(
                      _currentXAndYSelection["Series 2"].x, charts.RangeAnnotationAxisType.domain,
                      endLabel: _currentXAndYSelection["Series 2"].x.toString(),
                      color: charts.MaterialPalette.black,
                      dashPattern: [2,3],
                      labelStyleSpec: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                        color: charts.MaterialPalette.black,
                      ),
                      //color: charts.MaterialPalette.yellow.shadeDefault
                    ) ,
                    charts.LineAnnotationSegment(
                      _currentXAndYSelection["Series 2"].y, charts.RangeAnnotationAxisType.measure,
                      labelPosition: charts.AnnotationLabelPosition.inside,
                      labelAnchor: charts.AnnotationLabelAnchor.start,
                      labelDirection: charts.AnnotationLabelDirection.auto,
                      color: charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
                      dashPattern: [2,3],
                      startLabel:
                      "Series 2: ${_currentXAndYSelection["Series 2"].y.toString()}",
                      labelStyleSpec: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                        color: charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]) :
                  charts.ChartTitle(""),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Am using the latest version of the package:

```
charts_flutter: ^0.9.0
```

Many thanks for looking and your help :-)

Comment: It looks like ot might relate to this: https://github.com/google/charts/issues/118

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the best answer - so if someone can suggest a better solution I'll select that as the answer!

I ended up using an AbsorbPointer widget to temporally stop taps registering on the chart area.  This stops the failed assertion most of the time and when it does assert the app recovers.

However it is not very elegant and is a bit laggy - I believe there may be an underlying issue with the package see:

[Can't refresh chart before 1 second #118](https://github.com/google/charts/issues/118)

Updated code for listener:

```
 _onSelectionChanged(charts.SelectionModel model) async {
 Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).whenComplete(() {
   final selectedDatum = model.selectedDatum;

   if(selectedDatum.isNotEmpty){

     //setState((){_disableTaps= true;});

     selectedDatum.forEach((charts.SeriesDatum datum) {

       _currentXAndYSelection.containsKey(datum.series.displayName) ?
       _currentXAndYSelection.update(datum.series.displayName, (value) => XVsYData(datum.datum.x, datum.datum.y)) :
       _currentXAndYSelection.putIfAbsent(datum.series.displayName, () => XVsYData(datum.datum.x, datum.datum.y));

     });

     setState(() {_disableTaps= false;});
     //Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) => setState(() {_disableTaps= false;}));
   }
 });
```

}

Absorb pointer in widget tree:

```
AbsorbPointer(
            absorbing: _disableTaps,
            ignoringSemantics: _disableTaps,
            child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-20,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
            child: charts.LineChart(
```

Using set state to disable the taps:

```
changedListener: (model) {
                    setState(() {
                      setState((){_disableTaps= true;});
                    });
                    _onSelectionChanged(model);
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively as per the solution here:

[500 ms was too low for tabs with loaded content. Used to make chart blank with fast switches. #288](https://github.com/google/charts/pull/288/files)

Editing chart_container.dart to reduce to 100ms

```
    /// The minimum time required before the next configuration change.
  static const configurationChangeThresholdMs = 100;
```

Making this change allows the chart to be tapped continually without the assertion being raised.

Hopefully this push will be accepted into the package eventually!